# Inifinte Recursive loop I can't Solve?

Tags: java, recursion

I am developing a program that recursively generates the frequencies of the tones in a scale. Each frequency is the twelfth root of two higher than the previous one. The program must use recursion (ugh, education). When I use this method, I just get the initial tone repeated over and over and over again. Why is that?

```
public static void scale(double x, double z){
double y;
  if(z == x){
     y = z * Math.pow(2, (1/12));
     System.out.println(y);
     scale (y, y); 
   }
   else if(z >= (2 * x) - 1 || z <= (2 * x) + 1){
     y = z;
     System.out.println();
   }
   else{
     y = z * Math.pow(2, (1/12));
     scale (y, y);
   }
  System.out.println(y);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is that?

Because of Java's integer division.  Specifically, `1/12` becomes `0`, not `0.083333333`, because an `int` must be yielded.  Then `2` raised to the power `0` is `1` and `y` is the same as `z`.

Use `double` literals to force floating-point division.

```
1.0/12.0
```

Comment: I always forget about integer division..... thank you so much. Always helps to have a second pair of eyes when you're still learning.

Comment: To be complete: Java is not the only language that does this; to be safe, use floating point literals if you're working with floating points as a general rule of thumb.